# Obtaining value of a certain field from click event of a list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i have something like this

```
  <ul class="patient-class" id="patientSelection">
            <li>          
                <label for="plist">        
                    <div class="patient-details"><span class="pheading">Foo</span><span class="page"><a href="SomeLink">14 years</a></span>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </li>
  </ul>
```

Now I have a jquery function that tells me which `li` item is clicked

```
<script>
        $("#patientSelection li").click(function() {
          alert('Clicked list.'+$(this).value);
         });
</script>
```

Now my question is how can i alert out the link to the 14 years. which is `SomeLink`. Essentially i just want to capture the linked text ?

Comment: Is it the only link inside an li??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the anchor element, the you can get [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
$("#patientSelection li").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('.page a').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="patient-class" id="patientSelection">
    <li>
        <label for="plist">        
      <div class="patient-details">
         <span class="pheading">Foo</span>
          <span class="page"><a href="SomeLink">14 years</a></span>
          </div>
         </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can we tell it to look for `a` only under the span with class `page` ?

Comment: @JamesFranco, There is no anchor as child of `pheading` class, However if you have one just change the selector i.e. `$(this).find('.pheading a')`

Comment: i meant `page` sorry

Comment: @JamesFranco, then `$(this).find('.page a')` I have also updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use `.find()` to find the descendants of the `li's` element being clicked  :

```
$(this).find( 'a' ).text();
```